# Slackware Web server not loading PHP MySQL extensions even though they exist in the right directory

Tags: php, http, mysqli

I am running into a problem loading MySQL PHP extensions when starting HTTPD and PHP is enabled.  I am running a Slackware 14.2 distro.  I recently began investigating using PHP with my web server for authentication purposes against a MySQL database.  I enabled PHP in my HTTPD.conf file, restarted HTTPD and a simple .php script renders the Hello world portion from the PHP tags as it should.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

However when I run a php login script that tries to access MariaDB to grab usernames and passwords I get the following in my HTTPD error log.

```
[Sun Jun 14 18:18:59.734808 2020] [php7:error] [pid 2830:tid 140204551653120] [client XXX:59322] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in XXX.php:10\nStack trace:\n#0 XXX/login.php(12): require_once()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in XXX/config.php on line 10, referer: http://www.divemanagement2.com/
```

When I check the php version I get the following result:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/extensions/mysqli.so (/usr/lib64/php/extensions/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats), /usr/lib64/php/extensions/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/extensions/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/extensions/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib64/php/extensions/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator), /usr/lib64/php/extensions/pdo_mysql.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/extensions/pdo_mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/extensions/wddx.so (/usr/lib64/php/extensions/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/extensions/wddx.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/extensions/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.7 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2020 15:34:50) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Here are the extensions I have enabled in php.ini

```
extension=bcmath.so
extension=bz2.so
extension=calendar.so
extension=ctype.so
extension=curl.so
extension=dba.so
extension=dom.so
extension=enchant.so
extension=exif.so
extension=ftp.so
extension=gd.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=gmp.so
extension=iconv.so
extension=intl.so
extension=ldap.so
extension=mbstring.so
; extension=mysql.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=odbc.so
extension=openssl.so
zend_extension=opcache.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=pdo_odbc.so
extension=pspell.so
extension=shmop.so
extension=snmp.so
extension=soap.so
extension=sqlite3.so
extension=tokenizer.so
extension=wddx.so
extension=xmlreader.so
extension=xsl.so
extension=zip.so
extension=zlib.so
```

Note -- I have commented out mysql.so account I have read that after ver 5 mysql.so has been deprecated for mysqli.so and I am running PHP version 7.  Please advise if this is not true.

What I don't understand is the output from php -i advising that it cannot load the mysqli.so extension as it is here in /usr/lib64/php/extensions:

```
# ls -l
total 4764
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   39360 Jun  9 15:35 bcmath.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   27288 Jun  9 15:35 bz2.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   35160 Jun  9 15:35 calendar.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   14520 Jun  9 15:35 ctype.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  101496 Jun  9 15:35 curl.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   65248 Jun  9 15:35 dba.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  167960 Jun  9 15:35 dom.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   27160 Jun  9 15:35 enchant.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   92960 Jun  9 15:35 exif.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   64376 Jun  9 15:35 ftp.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  114072 Jun  9 15:35 gd.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   14648 Jun  9 15:35 gettext.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   76992 Jun  9 15:35 gmp.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   52000 Jun  9 15:35 iconv.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  489880 Jun  9 15:35 intl.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   97632 Jun  9 15:35 ldap.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1063608 Jun  9 15:35 mbstring.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  142400 Jun  9 15:35 mysqli.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  269520 Jun  9 15:35 mysqlnd.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   76864 Jun  9 15:35 odbc.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  561856 Jun  9 15:35 opcache.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  174040 Jun  9 15:35 openssl.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  109880 Jun  9 15:35 pdo.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   35456 Jun  9 15:35 pdo_mysql.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   31448 Jun  9 15:35 pdo_odbc.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   35736 Jun  9 15:35 pdo_sqlite.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   27064 Jun  9 15:35 pspell.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   14648 Jun  9 15:35 shmop.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   56312 Jun  9 15:35 snmp.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  315584 Jun  9 15:35 soap.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   64832 Jun  9 15:35 sqlite3.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   60480 Jun  9 15:35 tidy.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22904 Jun  9 15:35 tokenizer.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   35512 Jun  9 15:35 xmlreader.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   85080 Jun  9 15:35 xmlrpc.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   35704 Jun  9 15:35 xsl.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   72824 Jun  9 15:35 zip.so*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   52224 Jun  9 15:35 zlib.so*
```

Can anyone explain to me why the mysqli extension will not load even though it exists in the exact directory that is being searched on initialization?  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Did you install php7.0-mysql or which ever version of PHP you are using?

Comment: I did not install php7.0-mysql account the mysqli.so was already in the extensions directory.  My understanding is that when Slackware upgraded PHP recently through slackpkg it had updated the mysql(i) package as well.  Is this not right?